# How can I suppress client-side validation messages in MVC3/jQuery unobtrusive validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I am using the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute to indicate that a certain model property is required.

Without rolling my own Required validation attribute, is there a reasonably simple way to suppress validation messages on the client-side while still allowing them to show up when triggered server-side via Html.ValidationSummary()?  I still want the validation to occur and even highlight the input element, but I don't want a "xyzField is Required" message to appear for this specific Required attribute.

I do need the ValidationMessageFor to remain operational for all other ValidationAttributes on this model property - it's only the Required one that I'd like to suppress.

My reasoning is thus: I have several small fields in close proximity, and the Required messages are overkill and too busy.  Especially given that "Required" is the most frequent offender.  It's quite clear that the field is blank, yet required (has * required symbol, plus highlights in red when left empty).

Any ideas?  I know a custom validator isn't difficult - I have a few of them already, but I'd like to learn if there's a way to control this behavior that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

You should take out all the Validation Message For helper like:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
```

And then leave the validation summary helper at the top of your form:

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
```

You would have to post the code if you need a more specific answer.

What about leaving the error message blank in the model?  For example in your required attribute it would be `[Required]` or `[Required(ErrorMessage="")]`

See this post: [Validation outside model](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/performing-simple-validation-cs)

Comment: Thanks - maybe I didn't explain it clearly, but I have other validation attributes on the same Model Property for which I need the ValidationMessageFor, so removing it entirely is not an option.

Comment: I could leave the error message blank in the model, but I do want the error message to display in the validation summary.  You know...have my cake and eat it too :)

Comment: I believe the ValidationSummary only shows after a post back.  So, you could set the  ModelState.AddModelError("", "Some Error Text"); in the controller and then when the screen posts back it should show that error message.

Comment: On MVC3, the ValidationSummary seems to be triggered to display client-side if client-side validation is enabled, and there's a rule that prevents the page from posting